# Question with regard to queueing theory

Tags: queueing-theory

I am just in the midst of examn preparation and ask myself if somebody could help me with the following queueing problem:

A local country garage has one petrol pump. On average, customers are served at a rate of 6 per minute.
On normal days, customers arrive at the rate of 30 every 10 minutes. Arrivals follow a Poisson distribution and service times follow an exponential distribution.

a. What is the average number of customers in the queue?

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Relevant formula:
$$\rho = \frac{\lambda}{\mu}$$
$$N(M/M/1)=\frac{\rho}{1-\rho}$$

Comment: Thanks a lot. That hint helped me getting on the right track.